# Assign custom id for user on registering

Tags: 7, hooks, users

I need to assign custom ids for all users. The Id will come from API and its depend on other filled by user custom field. Witch hook should I use and witch variable holds id value?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're referring to a login ID - you should be able to use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to access the registration form, and create a default value.

get [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module and use dpm($form) in that function to look through the array to find the exact element you want to change.

after that you can probably use a number of options to hide the element, including css so that the user can't change it before being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to add a secondary ID field, separate from UID? If so, the user entity is fieldable, and you could probably use [hook_user_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_update/7) or [hook_user_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7) to populate the field, using aggregated the data from other user fields.

If I follow you correctly, it would be something like 'field_1 + field_2' comprise the new "ID" field you're creating. In which case, one of these hooks will achieve what you're looking for. Feel free to provide further clarification if needed.